# c++ comparison operators overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, structure

I have a problem overloading == operator for a structure.

```
struct str
{
    string nowString;
    int lastIndex;
};
bool operator < (const str A, const str B)
{
    return(A.nowString < B.nowString);
}
bool operator == (const str A, const str B)
{
    if (A.nowString == B.nowString && A.lastIndex == B.lastIndex)
        return(true);
    else
        return(false);
}
```

I have

```
    set <str> A;
    A.insert({"a", 1});
    A.insert({"a", 1});
    A.insert({"a", 2});
    A.insert({"b", 1});
    for (auto t = A.begin(); t != A.end(); t++)
    {
        cout << (*t).nowString << " " << (*t).lastIndex << endl;
    }
```

and I get

```
a 1
b 1
```

as an output, but I want to get

```
a 1
a 2
b 1
```

How to make set compare elements using both values in the structure, not the first one, as it seems to do now?

Comment: Since you managed to compare "both values" in the `==` overload, can you explain what is unclear to you about doing exactly the same in the `<` overload? The shown `<` overload compares only one of them, so, change the logic to appropriately compare both class members, so what exactly is your question?

Comment: Side note: defining `==` and `<` so that the two functions are not consistent with each other is something you can do, but you really shouldn't.

Answer (score 4):

[`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) uses `std::less` as the default comparator, which uses `operator<` for comparasion. And in your defined `operator<` only the data member `nowString` is mentioned. (Note that `operator==` is not used for determining uniqueness.)

> Everywhere the standard library uses the [*Compare*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) requirements, uniqueness is determined by using the equivalence relation. In imprecise terms, two objects `a` and `b` are considered equivalent if neither compares less than the other: `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`.

You can change the `operator<` to

```
bool operator < (const str& A, const str& B)
{
    return std::tie(A.nowString, A.lastIndex) < std::tie(B.nowString, B.lastIndex);
}
```

Comment: I tested it now and I did not get the result I need. I want to check the equality using both values of structure, but check less using only nowString. Is there a way to do that?
Like: `a 10` and `a 1` are placed before `b 1` or `b 2` no matter what the number is, but `a 1` and `a 10` are not equal.

Comment: @ALEX Like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4f5L2evdZkFvj5CS)?

Comment: @ALEX If you check less using only `nowString`, `a 10` and `a 1` would be equal in terms of ordering. But it seems you expect `a 1` to come before `a 10`, shouldn't it follow then that `a 1` is less then `a 10`?

Comment: Thanks, the only thing is I need to update to c++11 to use tie.

Comment: @ALEX artm provided an implementation which works with pre-C++11 too, the effect is the same.

Answer (score 1):

> How to make set compare elements using both values in the structure, not the first one

You can do logical OR:

```
bool operator<(const str A, const str B)
{
    return ((A.nowString < B.nowString) ||
            (A.nowString == B.nowString && A.lastIndex < B.lastIndex));
}
```

Comment: This was certainly the correct answer before C++11, but the std::tie() way is quite appealing these days.